# confluent-kafka based consumer in Python does not work

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Very new to kafka and Avro. I am stuck with a problem and can not seem to figure out what is going wrong here. I had written a producer and consumer of kafka which uses Avro as the serialization format. The producer code is working properly. As after running that code when I run the `kafka-avro-console-consumer` it give me as following -

```
bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --property schema.registry.url=http://127.0.0.1:8081 --from-beginning
{"name":{"string":"Hello World!"}}
{"name":{"string":"Hello World!"}}
{"name":{"string":"Hello World!"}}
```

However, when I try to do the same using python (following this the most basic [example](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) ) I write the following code -

```
from confluent_kafka import KafkaError
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroConsumer
from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer import SerializerError


class AvroConsumerAdapter(object):

    def __init__(self, topic='test'):
        self.topic = topic
        self.consumer = AvroConsumer({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
                                      'schema.registry.url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8081',
                                      'group.id': 'mygroup'})
        self.consumer.subscribe([topic])

    def start_consuming(self):
        running = True
        while running:
            try:
                msg = self.consumer.poll(10)
                if msg:
                    print(msg.value())
                    if not msg.error():
                        print("Here - 1")
                        print(msg.value())
                    elif msg.error().code() != KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
                        print("here-2")
                        print(msg.error())
                        running = False
                    else:
                        print('Here-3')
                        print(msg.error())
            except SerializerError as e:
                print("Message deserialization failed for %s: %s" % (msg, e))
                running = False
            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)
                running = False

        self.consumer.close()
```

This client stays there forever and never prints anything. I am not sure what is wrong here. Can anyone please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [topic config options](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md#topic-configuration-properties) -- you need to set `auto.offset.reset': 'smallest'` if you want to process all of the data currently in the topic. By default it's `largest` which means it'll only show new rows of data produced. You can verify this by leaving your current Python code running and producing new messages to the topic - you should see the Python code pick them up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped me to understand and get over the problem